# Static route to access IP/subnet beyond 2 interfaces

Tags: linux, routing, route

[networkmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lUt1.png)

I'm trying to reach the CCTV camera feed remotely. By connecting to WireGuard VPN server in my home. The CCTV video server is also connected by VPN profile, its location is in my shop. The video server has wireless card which works as access point for wireless camera.

The problem is, I can access the video server IP and see footage/liveview/control panel. But I cannot ping or reach the wireless card or even the camera at all. However, if I connect to the wlan0 with my laptop, I can see the feed of the camera.

VPN server is running Debian OS. While the video server and wireless Camera are running on RasberryPI OS.

I tried using ip tables to allow traffic packets to pass through, static route add and tried to investigate by tracert. But nothing worked.

Please help me setting this tricky static route

VPN conf on server:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <contents-of-client-privatekey>
Address = serverip/24
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = <contents-of-server-publickey>
Endpoint = myserverip:port
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/32
```

Comment: Please provide all of your VPN configurations (just hide the keys and change the public IP addresses).

Comment: So there's only one VPN between two peers? I have trouble to understand the setup. Also if that's the case, then 0.0.0.0/32 is a mistake (it should be 0.0.0.0/0 but that's probably not enough for a router rather than end node with the default `Table = auto` that does a lot of things with routes). If 3 peers are involved, then 0.0.0.0/0 either can't be used on the one seeing two peers. Hope this can help you, I'm leaving it here.